# Will there be any issues when JQUERY Datepicker used with AJAX Update panel..?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, asynchronous

i have used JQuery date picker in form- form contains just one text box and when we clicks on it--> it pops up the JQUERY datepicker.

In other web form in same project --> i have used script manager, Update panel and one textbox --> when click on it - am not getting JQUERY Datepicker Popped.??

What will be the issue.?? **Any problem with-> async. postback triggers**..?/

Will there be any issues when **JQUERY Datepicker** used with **AJAX controls**..??

Answer (score 1):

Do you initialize the datepicker correctly on PanelUpdate ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".clDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Also for the update panel to fix again the DatePicker after the ajax update you need the foloowing code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
     $(".clDate").datepicker();
}
</script>
```

Update:About the Sys. -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx